# PySpark - null pointer exception on large data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I keep getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error when I try to do something with a data frame.

The line that causes it is this
`df_3 = df_2.groupBy("id").pivot("key").agg(collect_list("value"))`

I know that there are no nulls in the data frame and have verified this. This issue seems to be with the size of the data frame? For example, if I add this line before the one above, it works fine:
`df_2 = df_2.limit(5)`.

I have even tried filtering `df_2` for specific values in the `key` column, but even that causes the null pointer exception:
`df_2 = df_2.filter(df_2.key == 'text').collect()`

I am also unable to do things such as count the number of rows in `df_2`:
`print(df_2.count())` -- these all cause the null pointer exception.

I know that if the `df_3` worked as intended, there would be ~500+ columns (from the values in `key`), which is why I am trying to filter that column for specific values beforehand. *emphasized text*Is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: Having this as well.  NPE on things such as count() and write_dynamic_frame.from_options(...) I have had some success increasing the maximum number of workers.

Comment: I git this issue as well. Did you find the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of pyspark functions (RegexTokenizer is one) that put phantom nulls in your data set. It does not help to df.dropna() because pyspark can't find the phantom nulls either. And it does not help to change nullable and containsNull to false in the schema of the data frame, e.g.:

root

|-- sparseTokens: array (nullable = false)

|    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)

You can find the function that's inserting phantom nulls by going through function by function and doing a print(df.count()) before and after the function. If it performs the count before the function, and throws a null pointer exception after the function; then you have your culprit. To narrow the list down to the most likely functions, I'd check anything with a regex in the name of the function.